# Only one-way implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is a basic question about implication. In constructive logic, we have $\Rightarrow$ for implication and $\Leftrightarrow$ for bi-implication. If we want to express *only* one-way implication, we can perhaps have the following:
$$(A\Rightarrow B)\wedge(B\not\Rightarrow A).$$
That is, $A$ implies $B$ but not vice versa. But as far as I know, $\not\Rightarrow$ is not a connective in the object language but is used at the metal-level. Is there any way to express $B\not\Rightarrow A$ in the object language? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $B\wedge\neg A$?

Comment: Since you mention constructive logic, let me point out that, unless I've mad a mistake, $\neg(B\to A)$ is constructively equivalent to $\neg((\neg B)\lor A)$ (even though $B\to A$ is weaker than $(\neg B)\lor A)$) and also to $(\neg\neg B)\land(\neg A)$. But these are weaker than $B\land(\neg A)$.

Comment: At the meta-level,  $==>$  is not used to express material implication, but logical implication :  " A logically implies B iff there is *no possible case* in which A is true and B is false". Make sure you understand the difference between material implication and logical implication.  See Seymour Lipschutz,  Outline of set theory (additional chapter at the end of the book).

Answer (score 4):

$$\lnot (B \implies A)$$
equivalently,
$$\lnot (\lnot B \lor A)$$
equivalently,
$$B \land \lnot A$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use material implication as

$$(P\implies Q)\iff (\lnot P \vee Q)$$

So, you can replace $ B$ does not imply $ A $ by
$$\lnot( \lnot B \vee A) $$
or
$$B \wedge \lnot A$$

Answer (score 0):

> If we want to express *only* one-way implication, we can perhaps have the following:
> $$(A\Rightarrow B)\wedge(B\not\Rightarrow A).$$ Is there any way to express $B\not\Rightarrow A$ in the object language?

It sounds like you want $$∀x(Ax→Bx)\;∧\;∃x(Bx∧¬Ax)$$ or, equivalently, $$∃y∀x\,\Big((Ax→Bx)∧By∧¬Ay\Big).$$

Notice that $$(A\to B)\wedge\color{red}{B \land\lnot A},$$ is tautologically equivalent to the simpler $$\color{red}{B \land\lnot A}.$$